# Switch Case, couldn't understand

Tags: php, switch-statement

I am trying to learn `switch case` php code. Here is the program that is working fine when using break.

```
for ($i=1;$i<=100;$i++) {
switch(true) {
        case ( $i%5 == 0  && $i%3 == 0 ):
            print 'foobar';
            break;
        case ( $i%3 == 0  ):
            print 'foo';
            break;
        case ( $i%5 == 0 ):
            print 'bar';
            break;
        case ( $i%5 != 0  && $i%3 != 0 ):
            print $i;
            break;
    } 
    echo '<br>';
}
```

But when I use the following code, it is giving me unexpected results:

```
for ($i=1;$i<100;$i++) {
switch(true) {
    case ( $i%3 == 0  ):
        print 'foo';
    case ( $i%5 == 0 ):
        print 'bar';
    default:
        print $i;
}
echo '<br>';
}
```

What is wrong in the second example?? Will `default` executes even when any above case is executed?? Also why `$i%5` case is running for when `$i` equals to 3??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the first one uses `break`, and the second snippet doesn't.

If you don't add `break`, the code from the next case will also be executed, even if that condition isn't met.

That is just how `switch` works in PHP, and in a couple of other C-like languages as well. It differs from the (similar) `case` statement as you may know it from Pascal-like languages and SQL.

Comment: so, it works like, if a case returns true, then all following cases will executes??

Comment: Correct. So you need `break` to stop it from doing that.

Answer (score 0):

In a PHP `switch()` statement, once a `case` has been met, every following line of code will be executed until either a `break` or the end of the block.

This allows for the intentional use of what's called a "fall through"

That is why your first example works and your second example did not do as you expected.